# Stripe Create User Function in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, stripe-payments

I was just wondering if there was a simple function to create a customer in the Stripe API from my app in Swift? Instead of having to create a manual HTTP post request to my server, "createCustomer.php", and then retrieve the results (This is what I do right now).

I tried to search this up on Google, but I can't seem to find anything. I simply want the user to save their card details for later user, that's why I am in need of creating a customer.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Will you please send me the file for createCustomer.php

Answer (score 3):

Except for payment information tokenization (which is done via Stripe's [iOS](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios) or [Android](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/android) SDKs in mobile apps, and [Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout) or [Stripe.js](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js) in web apps), all API requests must be sent from a backend server.

The reason is that aside from token creation, all other API requests must be sent using your secret API key. You cannot embed or share the secret API key with your mobile app in any way, as it would then be possible for an attacker to retrieve it and use it to issue API requests on your behalf.

This is why there is no Swift function to [create a customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_customer) -- the customer creation must be done from your backend, using the server-side language of your choice.

Comment: I see. I stumbled upon the example project on GitHub, as I was wondering how I was going to save the credit card for later use. However, I couldn't find anything regarding any saving or even retrieving of any customer data. If I was to fetch customer information in an attempt to grab card details, would this be done through the app or through backend?

Comment: You'd use the iOS SDK in the app to collect and tokenize the card information, then send the token to the backend and use in a customer creation request to save the card on Stripe's server. On your backend, you'd save the resulting customer ID so you can use it to create charges for this customer in the future.

Comment: Okay, cool. Do you have any suggestions on how I would retrieve the connected cards for each specific customer? I am using Stripe Connect, as well.

Comment: @Ywain I want to create application for ride and want to create two types of account 1) Driver Account & 2) Customer Account.

I have completed flow for driver by create Express account but not got any idea for Customer account.